# Rounding to 0.05 taxes what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, math, rounding

I'm super stuck on this problem and I don't know where the math is going wrong.
here goes..

Calculate the tax on these 2 products. tax should be rounded to the nearest 0.05.

product_ONE price = $47.50 with a tax of 15%---answer should be $54.65;

47.50 * 15 / 100 = 7.125

7.125 / 0.05 = 142.5 -> rounded you get 143

143 * 0.05 = 7.15 tax

$47.50 + $7.15 = $54.65 -> great I got what I should;

product_TWO price = $11.25 with a tax of 5% ---answer should be $11.85;

11.25 * 5 / 100 = 0.5625

0.5625 / 0.05 = 11.25 -> rounded you get 11

11 * 0.05 = 0.55 tax;

$11.25 + $0.55 = $11.80 -> but the answer should be 11.85...how???

if you are going to say you should round 0.55 to 0.6
then why not round 7.15 to 7.2 ??? and then product_ONE answer wont match...

can someone explain please if its my math or if I've been given the wrong answers? thanks

Comment: What libraries are you using for rounding?

Comment: Why do you think the total with tax for product 2 should be 11.85?  `11.25 * 1.05 = 11.8125`, which when rounded to the neared `0.05` is `11.80`, which is what you got.

Comment: you should ask attorney for this question

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: And how does these questions get upvote?

Comment: Try `Math.round(x * 20) / 20.0;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second example seems to imply that, against the task description. If it is correct and complete, in the line

```
0.5625 / 0.05 = 11.25
```

you get to round up to 12, not to nearest integer (paying too much tax is preferable to evading tax).

Then

```
12*0.05 = 0.60
```

and the result is as desired.

---

Of course, if "rounding to nearest" is the task description, then your result in the second case is the correct one.

Comment: thanks so much, you are right it should be rounded UP which solved both problems I misread the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. the original problem says rounded UP not just rounded, at which point.

0.5625 / 0.05 = 11.25 -> rounded UP = 12;

12 * 0.05 = 0.6;

0.60 + 11.25 = 11.85 :)

like @LutzL said.